# В PrestaShop не отображаются результаты при импорте

Tags: prestashop, импорт, prestashop-1.7

[image: Появляется вот это вместо нормальных результатов]

Не знаю что делать , помогите.

Comment: проверьте правельность заполнения файла импорта